# What is the ANSI escape equivalent of `tput sgr0`?

Tags: terminal, tput, ansi

To avoid a subshell, what are the ANSI escape equivalents of `tput sgr0` for an ANSI-compatible terminal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could answer that by looking at the output of [**`infocmp`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html):
using the **`-1`** option to print one capability per line for a given setting of **`TERM`** (i.e., "ansi"), simplifying a **`grep`**:

```
infocmp -1 ansi |grep sgr0=
```

and seeing (for example)

```
sgr0=\E[0;10m,
```

which tells you that you could do

```
printf '\033[0;10m'
```

to get the same effect as

```
tput -T ansi sgr0
```

But you're not using ***ANSI***, but rather some particular terminal, and though the ones you're using are similar, not all are identical.  It's more likely that your **`TERM`** variable is set to something like "xterm", which (omitting the terminal type) gives

```
sgr0=\E(B\E[m,
```

The common part is the **`\E[m`**, which is the terminfo syntax for **`\033[m`**.  The other characters in each sequence are resetting the alternate character set (and can depend on the terminal type).

Comment: Is `ansi` an option?

Comment: **`-T ansi`** is an option, telling **`tput`** which terminal description to use.

Comment: Please consider explaining the entire command, e.g. `-1 ansi`, so I don't have to look it up or test personally to see that results in each variable printing on its own line.